# jQuery and Ajax with json - fails in IE

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, jquery

I'm using jQuery (1.7.0) to make a json/ajax call to Spotify.  The following code works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but causes an error (Error: Access is denied.) in IE.

```
 $.ajax({
     url: 'http://ws.spotify.com/lookup/1/.json',    
     type: 'GET',    
     dataType: 'json',    
     cache: true,    
     data: {    
       uri: "someartist",    
       extras: "album"    
     },    
     success: successfn,    
     error:function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {    
       alert("networking error: "+errorThrown+'\n'+status+'\n'+xhr.statusText);    
     }
 });
```

The success function is called in Chrome and FF, but the error function is called in IE with the above message.  I have set cors to true: `jQuery.support.cors = true;`.

It works on Chrome and FF both locally and on my server, it works in IE locally but not on the server.  Changing `cache: false` causes problems at the spotify end - doesn't line additional parameters, so I get a "bad request" error.

Grateful for any pointers.

Thanks

Abo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are relying on the spotify url to give a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` in their header to allow cross domain requests from all domains. Internet explorer however doesn't support this, so it gives access denied.

[access-control-allow-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control) explained. (TLDR: Servers may allow cross domain ajax in their headers)

If you need this to work in IE, you could use spotify's JSONP API if they have one or make the AJAX request in flash, which works in all browsers and passes the requests response data to your javascript.

Comment: This was really useful! Thanks.  Is it straightforward to write some php to use curl to get the data and then pass it to my javascript?  I've never used flash and I don't think spotify has a jsonp interface.

Comment: You don't need to use flash( other than to embed the .swf on your page), you use flXHR pretty much the same way you use jsXHR without cross browser differences. Read some documentation on their page to see how the API is used. Yes you can use your server as a proxy to retrieve the data since it's in same domain but this will put unnecessary load on your server.

Comment: The way you would use it with your server:
1. make ajax call to your server
2. your server uses curl to get data from spotify
3. your server returns the data to browser

Comment: yep - that's what I thought - should be simple?

Comment: yes but flXHR even has as [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/getify/flensed/blob/master/flXHR/flXHRproxy/jquery.flXHRproxy.js). I recommend this since the overhead is not negligible in the proxy solution: 2 requests will happen for every request.

Comment: Thanks to Esailija for this.  I had no idea that cross-domain calls were ever possible.  All I've ever read is, "Cross-domain Ajax calls are not permitted."

Comment: I've done a bit more digging and the reason it works in Chrome and FF is that they have implemented CORS and jQuery supports it.  The IE implementation is non-standard and jQuery has not supported it.  The Spotify api supports CORS so everything is fine - apart from IE.

Comment: @abonae, Yes that's what my answer said. It has nothing to do with jQuery though. But flash supports CORS, flash works in IE and flash can pass data to javascript so it's a good workaround.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer about using jsonp is correct; I want to add:

**Don't** set

```
jquery.support.cors = true;
```

I'm not sure why so many questions begin by stating they took that step. This property is meant to be read to find out if the browser supports CORS. You should only override it if you know differently, and in my experience it's accurate for all major browsers. Setting it to true doesn't enable the browser to use CORS, it just denies you the info that CORS is going to fail.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/

Answer (score 0):

can you give an example of returned data?

at a /guess/, it either has something to do with the filename ".json", or the JSON returned has something weird about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised this works on Chrome or Firefox. You shouldn't be able to run cross-domain JSON requests.

If Spotify API supports it, you should use JSONP in order to access resources from other domains.

Also see: [No response from jQuery ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176530/no-response-from-jquery-ajax-call)

Comment: Thanks for this.  Spotify does not seem to support jsonp.  Presumably I could write a piece of php that would get the data via curl and then return it on the same domain?php Would I be able to

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this working in FF.  You can't make cross-domain Ajax calls.  So I'm not sure what's going on when you say that it works in FF.  But I just tried the following in FF and I got the error.  So all you can do is make the call on the server side and then include the results in your page.

http://jsfiddle.net/2XWGn/

Comment: It does work in FF (and Chrome).  In the example you put in jsfiddle, you have copied the uri field which was made up!  If you try it with a real one (like spotify:album:4neXRfYbkqqdrw3E9Z4wol) the call succeeds.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I learned something important today.