# Why does IE 11 browser randomly have Content-Length=0 for jQuery AJAX POST requests?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-11, waffle

I'm working on Spring MVC based webapp.

Following are my environment details :-
`Java 1.8.0_162 (64 bit)`, `Spring 4.3.1`, `Apache Tomcat 8.0.49`, `Waffle-1.8.3` for SSO, `jquery-1.11.3` and `Google Charts API`.

Have put the following JavaScript code in one of the common JS files :-
`$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });`

The jQuery AJAX `POST` requests made to the server work flawlessly in **Mozilla** & **Chrome** browsers. 
But when it comes to **IE 11** browser, the jQuery AJAX `POST` requests work without fail only when the window is loaded for the first time. 
Then fail randomly & once failed, the subsequent requests also fail.

Following are the snapshots of the **Network** tab of the **IE 11** browser:-

1. **SUCCESSFUL** ajax `POST` request :
   [image]
2. **FAILED** ajax `POST` request :
   [image]

Both requests have the JSON object in their respective **request** bodies. 
But, the `Content-Length` property value is **416** (the total characters of the stringified JSON object) for the successful request & **0** for the failed one.
For the random failed `POST` request & the subsequent requests, the `Content-Length` is always **0**, but the computed JSON object is always present in the request body. 
In every request, the JSON object is built dynamically.

**UPDATE-1 (26March2018)** Following is the `Waffle` AD authentication configuration defined in the `web.xml` file :-

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>waffle.servlet.NegotiateSecurityFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>principalFormat</param-name>
        <param-value>fqn</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>roleFormat</param-name>
        <param-value>both</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>allowGuestLogin</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>securityFilterProviders</param-name>
        <param-value>
            waffle.servlet.spi.NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>waffle.servlet.spi.NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider/protocols</param-name>
        <param-value>
            Negotiate
            NTLM
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/welcome.do</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

*Only **1** URL i.e., `/welcome.do` (the initial URL that loads the webapp) is configured to invoke SSO authentication.*

Following is the JavaScript code that fires AJAX requests :-

```
function getData() {
    let dashboardFilterParams=new DashboardFilterParams(<passing the arguments to this constructor>);
    //alert(JSON.stringify(dashboardFilterParams));
    //console.dir(dashboardFilterParams);
    $.ajax({
            url: str_THIS_WA_URL+"/xyz/abcdXYZ.do?httpReqType=ajaxReq",
            data: JSON.stringify(dashboardFilterParams),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            mimeType: "application/json",
            type: "POST",
            success:function(responseData){
                        if(responseData && "success"===responseData.reqResult) {
                            //populating tables & drawing charts using Google Charts JS API if successfully fetched the data
                        } else {
                            //showing error message
                        }
                    },
            error:function(data,status,er) {
                        showTheMessage("danger","Error getting data");
                        console.log("error: "+JSON.stringify(data)+"\n status: "+status+"\n er:"+er);
                    }
     });
}
```

**IE 11** version details :

[image: IE 11 version details]

Also, I'm using the **Google Charts API** to render charts on the page. For which the requests are fired to the Google Charts API server. Does this effect in IE browser?

What is the solution to make it work in **IE 11** browser?

Answers to **Federico klez Culloca**'s questions in the comments section :

1. No error in the request (client) side. But the response from the server says `The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect`. and the response headers `Response    HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`.
2. There is absolute no difference in the request body contents.
3. The `str_THIS_WA_URL variable` points to the same domain as the webapp, i.e., the AJAX requests are within the current domain.

Adding timestamp (on **shawn**'s suggestion in the comments section below) to the URL did not solve the problem.

Comment: Any error/exception on the backend?

Comment: Please check the request body and see if it differs between the two calls. Also, if possible, please show the code doing the actual request.

Comment: I just noticed that your application is requesting data from a different domain. Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111489/jquery-and-ajax-with-json-fails-in-ie)?

Comment: Have you read [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2010/11/21/challenge-response-authentication-and-zero-length-posts/) describing an identical symptom? Could you be triggering that scenario?

Comment: i got a headache from this problem about 2 years ago... some answer on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328281/why-content-length-0-in-post-requests) helps me

Comment: What about appending some timestamp after your URL ? `"/xyz/abcdXYZ.do?httpReqType=ajaxReq&_=" + (new Date()).getTime()`

Comment: see maybe: [waffle#39](https://github.com/Waffle/waffle/issues/39) and [waffle#339](https://github.com/Waffle/waffle/issues/339)

Comment: Can you run wireshark and check the difference between calls from chrome and IE browser? Also you might want to have a look on the issue [here](https://github.com/Waffle/waffle/issues/346).

Answer (score 2):

IE does this as an optimization because it expects the server to reply with an HTTP/401 credential challenge and it would be a waste to transmit the body twice.

In your case since `/welcome.do` is secured with NTLM, IE now assumes that `/` *and everything below* is part of the secured protection space and thus applies the bodyless POST optimization to everything.

A fix would be to move `/welcome.do` to `/secured/welcome.do` and ensure that no unsecured resources are under `/secured`.

More details here: [Challenge-Response Authentication and Zero-Length Posts](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2010/11/21/challenge-response-authentication-and-zero-length-posts/).